# Perl, warn not working after XML::Smart save

Tags: perl, stderr

I realised there is a problem with warn after the use of XML::Smart save.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Smart;

my $XML = XML::Smart->new() ;

print STDOUT "Before save: Print to STDOUT works\n";
print STDERR "Before save: Print to STDERR works\n";
warn "Before save: Warn works\n";

$XML->save('newfile.xml') ;

print STDOUT "After save: Print to STDOUT works\n";
print STDERR "After save: Print to STDERR works\n";
warn "After save: Warn does not work\n";
```

Test is done in OSX 10.8.2 perl version 5.12.4 xml-smart version 1.77

This is probably closely related to the internal workings of XML::Smart but is there a way to restore printing of warn (reset STDERR).

[EDIT 19/3/2013]: In HP-UX constructor is also problematic. Workaround provided below by ikegami can be used for both new and save to overcome the issue.

Comment: This works fine for me. I am on Strawberry Perl 5 version 16.2. Are you sure you aren't missing the warning? It won't appear as the last line of output unless you start with `STDOUT->autoflush`.

Comment: Confirmed : same issue on archlinux x86_64, XML-Smart-1.77 and perl 5.16.2, you should fill a bug report. With `$|++`, nothing changes

Comment: This seems related to a function called `_unset_sig_warn()` defined in `XML::Smart::Shared` which tries to disable `$SIG{__WARN__}` by storing it in a lexical variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As TLP pointed out, the problem is related to XML::Smart's fiddling with `$SIG{__WARN__}`.

The following is a workaround to the bug:

```
{
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = $SIG{__WARN__};
    local $SIG{__DIE__}  = $SIG{__DIE__};
    $XML->save('newfile.xml') ;
}
```

As Borodin explains, this workaround localises the two elements of %SIG that XML::Smart modifies so that the damage is restricted to the enclosing block. The values are automatically restored at the end of the block, immediately after the call to `$XML->save`.

Comment: Thank you! This works great on OS-X but can you please elaborate on this workaround and what effect it has to actually make warn work? I will also try on Solaris my work machine.

Comment: @EvangelosValtos: What this work-around does is localize the two elements of `%SIG` that `XML::Smart` tinkers with, so that the damage is restricted to the enclosing block. The values are automatically restored at the end of the block, immediately after the call to `$XML->save`.